# Testing a form that gets choices from database in Django - database access not allowed

Tags: python, django, django-forms, pytest

I've got a test for my form that is erroring out because I have the form choices populating from a model. The error looks like this:

```
../myapp/tests/test_forms.py:5: in <module>
    from myapp.forms import AssignmentForm, AssignmentFormSet
myapp/forms.py:135: in <module>
    class MyDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
myapp/forms.py:138: in MyDetailForm
    choices=[(ey.end_year, ey.full_label()) for ey in Year.objects.all()]
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:268: in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:1186: in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:54: in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:1063: in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py:255: in cursor
    return self._cursor()
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py:232: in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
E   Failed: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.
```

It appears that it doesn't like me getting the `Year` objects for my choices in `MyDetailForm` which looks like this:

```
class MyDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):

    end_year = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[(ey.end_year, ey.full_label()) for ey in Year.objects.all()]
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyDetail
        fields = ["end_year", "is_current"]
        labels = {"is_current": "Current Sections"}
```

Is this a big no-no? How do I get around this so my tests will actually run?

This error pops before my tests ever run, so it's happening during my import statements.

If I change `[(ey.end_year, ey.full_label()) for ey in Year.objects.all()]` to `[]` my tests run as expected, but I don't want to have to change stuff in `forms.py` just for testing purposes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a callable in your choices.

```
def get_year_choices():
    return [(ey.end_year, ey.full_label()) for ey in Year.objects.all()]

class MyDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):

    end_year = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=get_year_choices
    )
```

You can then patch `get_year_choices` in your tests.

Moving the code to a callable also means that the database will be queried when the form is instantiated. At the moment, the query occurs when Django loads, which can cause errors when migrating a fresh database, or lead to stale results.

Comment: Excellent answer - thanks for the heads up about using the callable to keep the data fresh as to the form instantiation - hadn't thought about that! Cheers!